# ML2165 doesn't complete duplex jobs

Tags: linux, printing, printer, network-printer, cups

Not sure if this is the proper place to ask, I have a Samsung ML2165 wireless laser printer that I use with CUPS and rastertoqpdl (splix drivers, I believe) from Fedora 24.

The printer (or cups, not sure) has this nice feature where you select duplex mode and it prints odd pages first, stops with a red led on, you put the sheets on the tray again and it prints even pages taking care of the proper orientation.

Everything works fine for smallish documents but with bigger ones (let's say more than 40 pages) it hangs midway on the second stage. The green led keeps blinking, like when it's waiting to cool down a bit, but never starts printing again. It just hangs like that.

No error on the cups side, at least as far as I can tell. It says something like sending data to the printer. The only thing I can do is cancel the job and try with a smaller batch.

It feels like something times out, either on the Linux or on the printer side, but I have no idea about how to debug it.

The same thing happens no matter what type of connection I use on the CUPS side (socket, mdnsd, ipp).

Anyone ever had similar issues?